# Spring boot - No property ID found for type User

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Well, I searched Google and found many results, but none of them was able to answer my problem. So, here it goes.

I am trying to study Spring MVC and Spring Data JPA by doing a minimal implementation of pinterest clone. So, following is the parts of code which I think is relevant to my problem.

Repository Class:

```
public interface CourseStudentRepository extends JpaRepository <CourseStudent, Long> {

    List<CourseStudent> findByCourseInstructorId(Long instructorId);

    List<CourseStudent> findByStudentID (Long studentId);
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "course_student")
public class CourseStudent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Course course;

}
```

Error:

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.sha.serverside.repository.CourseStudentRepository.findByStudentID(java.lang.Long)! No property ID found for type User! Did you mean 'id'? Traversed path: CourseStudent.student.
```

Comment: Can you share `user` entity? I guess Spring Data JPA query for child tables won't work via interface query. You need to write explicit query.

Answer (score 2):

Error says there is no `ID` field is `Student` class but you use `List<CourseStudent> findByStudentID` in repository. Field name is case sensitive here, `ID` and `Id` is not the same.

Use `findByStudentId` instead of `findByStudentID`

```
List<CourseStudent> findByStudentId (Long studentId);
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: Please I'm new to java. why in spring boot we should respect the case-sensitive ? why is isn't just a method name ? please If you have any doc that could help me understanding this

Comment: @hakimamaarouf Here, CamelCase used and it's important because from method name it's split the fields names and without case it is not possible to find out the field name. And also create ambiguity.

Comment: I see, Thank you but if we use @Query (with nativeQuery true) and giving the query we won't need it isn't ?

Answer (score 2):

Take care of the case. The name must be `findByStudentId`. with lower case `d` at the end

Comment: Please I'm new to java. why in spring boot we should respect the case-sensitive ? why is isn't just a method name ? please If you have any doc that could help me understanding this

Comment: Because the name will be parsed by spring-data-jpa to a query.

Comment: Even if we use  @Query to specify the query with nativeQuery setted to true we have to respect that ?

Comment: No if you use @Query and especially nativeQuery=true that is another thing.